# Как работает youtube-dl?

Tags: python, html, .net, youtube, youtube-dl

Откуда [менеджер загрузок youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org) берет ссылки на видео? Хочу понять фундаментальную идею. Лазил в панели разработчика - нашел похожие [результаты](https://rr2---sn-i5h7lnls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1656626342&ei=Rsi9YuOKD4O6gQexhoW4BQ&ip=93.231.62.20&id=o-AOa0FwzSSakLrUKEwqK14FOwN5b2cy0mzaazyjJSRReq&itag=248&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C278&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=WM&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-i5h7lnls%2Csn-i5heen7d&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=26&initcwndbps=1592500&spc=4ocVC3T-0n_lB6GprHk_oozWppTqjuKevIptBRyWxDn9&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fwebm&ns=6szXjR_srrD8GS8cXblc-soG&gir=yes&clen=19516239&dur=175.933&lmt=1570031991943299&mt=1656604414&fvip=1&keepalive=yes&fexp=24001373%2C24007246&c=WEB&txp=2316222&n=YzYSrHHzA8R5cw&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIhAMf-JlGr9wgrljTKUXuGrZSrmvQSHxB6yjxIMoaWzonTAiBS9t4xUW7CA1UUofPppYQDGZupQfmB8RcE2Hpu7bEzcA%3D%3D&alr=yes&sig=AOq0QJ8wRgIhAJrGo6vrDHaayi-SlkTULBFUIF74YlMqyI-sBxyAug_sAiEA_n8Qb1SlaMXUYS0vPZ5I6TvdryLMhKsmNL2OyWW8OqI%3D&cpn=GSZYMmIkFQyPWdsV&cver=2.20220629.01.00&range=0-327590&rn=1&rbuf=0). В данном случае это видео, которое длиться около 10 секунд, а после просто заканчивается. Как так происходит? То же самое с аудио. Также в панели разработчика есть огромное количество нерабочих videoplayback типа [этого](https://rr2---sn-i5h7lnls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1656626342&ei=Rsi9YuOKD4O6gQexhoW4BQ&ip=93.231.62.20&id=o-AOa0FwzSSakLrUKEwqK14FOwN5b2cy0mzaazyjJSRReq&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=WM&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-i5h7lnls%2Csn-i5heen7d&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=26&initcwndbps=1592500&spc=4ocVC3T-0n_lB6GprHk_oozWppTqjuKevIptBRyWxDn9&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&ns=6szXjR_srrD8GS8cXblc-soG&gir=yes&clen=3222449&dur=175.961&lmt=1570033299132333&mt=1656604414&fvip=1&keepalive=yes&fexp=24001373%2C24007246&c=WEB&txp=2301222&n=YzYSrHHzA8R5cw&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgAT0bgLTpBxlGM0mrFB_fpyXvAnAGElCFMS55EFRzU98CIAb9lX84uzgR10lmn6Px6Yxg1m7Dzqy3i0QGHN1ImKYe&alr=yes&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIgWN1DVTjBX3ZPgU8R4zodTJZAP5Yj2qZYIX7H1uV_2J4CIQDm4sVRNVv3jAfKjtTiUQwcHkMSFBFTDaRmZOVuH53v6g%3D%3D&cpn=GSZYMmIkFQyPWdsV&cver=2.20220629.01.00&range=131641-275472&rn=4&rbuf=7318).

Но [рабочих ссылок на видео ресурсы](https://rr2---sn-i5h7lnls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1656625644&ei=jMW9Yu7EJvKXgAfRoruACw&ip=93.231.62.20&id=o-ANilndPHUPax9En9yOHN6y5nabfMTJ6sZ0nWNMDIOF9C&itag=18&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=WM&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-i5h7lnls%2Csn-4g5ednld&ms=au%2Conr&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=26&initcwndbps=1597500&spc=4ocVC6CXsR8ege9lh0zqsg7jSUdTci0&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&ns=Fa3UtP-LElcfghCEBiEN774G&gir=yes&clen=8916567&ratebypass=yes&dur=175.984&lmt=1570032012621580&mt=1656603693&fvip=3&fexp=24001373%2C24007246&c=WEB&txp=2316222&n=jChtH0hwIdS3Cl5EZOw&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIhALfF9JtUwWbPztmAFJhGnZyC5aoevGxRj83ilIGYmtvpAiBp_zWERovSkAKWiThSfsAQksgi5XfzwqCDY9KRjlVJ9w%3D%3D&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIgW6UhWgbUbYECg5m6sf7TnRggn0NRI4sA9LHRMkQWYO4CIQCwQOjOxiniokexPJdG8FiqkMQ2PBcgvKD1BT6sLYbrzw==), которые выдает и VLC, и youtube-dl не наблюдается. Старые гайды уже не актуальны.

**EDIT:**
В ссылке на 10-секундное видео был параметр `range=0-327590`. Если его убрать - скачает целиком.

Comment: Ну, прямо в [исходниках youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py) и посмотрите?

Comment: А эти ваши рабочие и нерабочие videoplayback — это кусочки HLS или MPEG-DASH видеопотока

Comment: @andreymal в исходниках копаться пытался, но, увы, не понимаю

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548884/is-there-a-youtube-api-that-gives-only-audio. Может поможет в раскопках

Comment: Я тут на днях покопался — оказывается, там всё поменяли и MPEG-DASH уже нету. Вот этот вот videoplayback — это ссылка на видеофайл целиком, а плеер просто выбирает нужный ему кусочек с помощью параметра range в ссылке. Если этот параметр убрать из ссылки, то видеофайл скачается целиком

Comment: Красавчик! Работает :)